# Is there a CSS Font Size/Line Height Calculator?

Tags: html, css

I watched some conference recently online, talking abt web typography. There was something mentioned about a web calculator for calculating `font-size/line-height` with the golden ratio. Any ideas where can I find it? Or what sizes do you use for your headers?

Answer (score 38):

The CSS property 'line-height' actually accepts a pure numerical value, which will work out the line height based on the font size set. If you want to use the golden ratio (1.61803399), then you could set this as the line height in the body.

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.618 sans-serif;
    }
```

As an example, setting a H1's font-size to 24px would produce a line-height of 39px (rounded up from 38.832).

Comment: For any font size, the line height must increase as the line width increases too

Comment: @Tom Care to elaborate, Tom? Using a unit-less value tells the browser to adjust the line height according to the font-size. I'm unsure as to where line width comes in to play here, but would be interested in your expanded thoughts.

Comment: As the line width is increased, the text becomes harder to read because the line height has not been increased to offset the effect of the width. There are 3 typographical dimensions: font size, line height, and line width. What if you wanted to use a 16px font size in a content width of 550px? What should your adjusted line height be in this case? According to you is 25.88, but the optimal is 25.00. This is just a further reading ;)

Comment: @Tom Thanks for expanding and I completely agree that type should be set properly, but it isn't always easily achievable in CSS. Depending how you set up your styles and markup, setting a `line-height` along with every `font-size` could result in unmanageable code in the future. At the very least a well-chosen base unit-less value will increase/decrease `line-height` along with the `font-size`, even if it is an odd pixel out from the optimum here and there. And then you can adjust key blocks of text case-by-case.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but just in case someone is still looking for references, this  (awesome) [Golden Ratio Typography Calculator](http://www.pearsonified.com/typography/)

Comment: But you miss this **[awsone article](http://www.pearsonified.com/2011/12/golden-ratio-typography.php)** from the author of that awsone Golden Ratio Calculator

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is [this calculator](http://modularscale.com/) from [this presentation](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/case-study-designing-with-modular-scale/).

Answer (score 0):

Was it [type-scale.com](http://type-scale.com/)? I use this for calculating all mine. It provides font size and line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Those looking for explicitly setting the `line-height` with the **Golden Ratio**, you can use:

```
line-height: 161.8%;
```

This will scale properly with different font sizes.